# Display an information message while the program is running

Tags: c#

I am working on a user interface in C#. When user click the 'start' button, a huge 'for loop' starts to work. This process takes several minutes.

I want that just before forloop a message is displayed and after the forloop the message will disappear automaticly. My aim is to give an information message like 'Running, please wait' to the user.

Is there anyway to do that?

Here is the loop. It scans an image and makes some processes.

```
for (var i = 0; i <3504 ; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 2306; j++)
        {
         ........
        }
```

Comment: Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hopefully the loop is threaded?

Comment: `async Task` with `IProgress` might be a possible alternative to the  `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what GUI framework you're using, so I'm going to assume Forms. WPF would be similar though.

Let's assume the work begins when you click a button named "button1". Create a `Form` subclass that is your message (called, for the sake of example, "MessageWaitForm"). Then you can use it like this:

```
private void SomeWork()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <3504 ; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < 2306; j++)
            {
             ........
            }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MessageWaitForm form = new MessageWaitForm())
    {
        form.Shown += async (sender1, e1) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => SomeWork());
            form.Close();
        }

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This causes your processing to be executed in a separate asynchronous task, starting once the message dialog has been shown. When the task finishes, execution will return to the `form.Close()` statement, allowing the message form to be automatically closed.

Note that I had to make some assumptions and fill out your code example some just so that a usable answer could be provided. The above may not match your exact implementation as it stands now, but hopefully you can understand the basic concept being illustrated and conform it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your code would look something like this? I haven't had a chance to compile this but it should be enough to get you started.

```
private void StartBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning = true;
    CodeIsRunning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    //Anything else needed (disable buttons, etc)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3504; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < 2306; j++)
            { 
                ... 
            }
        _isRunning = false;
    });
}
```