# How to call a background thread properly in a work in progress dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

The main window of our application opens a work in progress dialog which should call a background thread. The dialog should appear until the thread is finished:

```
var dialog = new WorkInProgressDialog();
dialog = ShowDialg;
```

The problem now is where/how to call the thread in `WorkInProgressDialog` constructor? If it is called in the constructor, the dialog will not be visible until the thread is finished.

Also the dialog should be automatically closed after the thread is completed.

Comment: Many options - you can use `Thread`, `BackgroundWorker` or ideally the new Task library, for example `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display an information message while the program is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052090/display-an-information-message-while-the-program-is-running)

Comment: There are lots of similar questions on StackOverflow, including the proposed duplicate. You should provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you've tried so far, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want/expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that will hopefully help you. Some simple markup for the WorkInProgressDialog:

```
<Window x:Class="WorkInProgressExample.WorkInProgressDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WorkInProgressDialog" Height="100" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>            

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="WorkProgressTextBlock">Work in progress...</TextBlock>
            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Name="WorkProgressBar"></ProgressBar>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
private bool _closeAuthorised = false;

public WorkInProgressDialog()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WorkProgressBar.Maximum = 10;
    WorkProgressBar.Minimum = 0;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Do whatever processing you need to here
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Any updates to the UI need to be done on the UI thread
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                WorkProgressBar.Value = i;
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        // Set the DialogResult and hence close, also on the UI thread
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            _closeAuthorised = true;
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }));

    });
}

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If the user uses ALT+F4 to try andclose the loading dialog, this will cancel it
    if (!_closeAuthorised)
        e.Cancel = true;
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Then where you want to use it:

```
var dialog = new WorkInProgressDialog();
bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the helpful example. Will the WorkInProgressDialog be closed only by setting DialogResult to true?

Comment: No problem. No, the dialog will close also if you set `this.DialogResult` to false. The difference is that from where you show the dialog (the last code block in my example) the bool? result will be false, rather than true. You could use this to indicate an error condition for example.

Comment: In case I misunderstood your question, I've also tweaked the answer to include handling for if the user tried to close the dialog with ALT+F4

Comment: Thank you again for your help and the extended example. Is it correct to say, that setting DialogResult to a value (either true or false) causes the WorkInProgressDialog to close? If yes, why? Will an event raised after setting DialogResult to a value?

Comment: Correct. Internally, the setter for `DialogResult` checks to see if the dialog is already closing, and if it isn't calls `this.Close()` for you. As to why, it's just the way that it's been developed. The dialog will raise the `Closing` event, followed by the `Closed` event. The `dialog.ShowDialog()` call in my example will block until the dialog is closed.